# How to make values in plist change based on build scheme

Tags: xcode, plist

I've a few different build schemes. 
The dev/test/accept schemes need to use use other values on certain plist variables than the production scheme.

How should I go about this?

[image]

Comment: Build Settings > Tap the plus button > Add user-defined setting > Name it as you want > configure > add to your plist file as $(NAME_IT_AS_YOU_WANT)

Comment: https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e

Comment: @pandarencodemaster your solution worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make three copies of your info.plist file as info_dev.plist, info_test.plist and info_accept.plist respectively. Change your plist variable values accordingly in each plist file as needed

Then select info_dev.plist and go to File inspector > Target Membership > Select 'dev' scheme. Repeat the same for other two files and select your schemes accordingly.

Now go to 'Build Settings' section and select your build target, e.g. 'dev'. Under Packaging, change the path of your Info.plist File to the new info_dev.plist. Repeat the same process for other targets.

This will pick the respective plist file configured for each build scheme while compiling.